# How to make multiple templates for same file type in vim?

Tags: c++, vim

So, i want vim to load different templates in my cpp files based on their name. I have these two lines in my vimrc

```
au BufNewFile *.cpp 0r ~/.vim/templates/skeleton.cpp
au BufNewFile *=.cpp 0r ~/.vim/templates/another.cpp
```

With this, whenever i create a file with "=" in it's name(at end), vim loads both of the templates but i only want it to load the second one.
How can i do that?

Comment: Try asking at https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this behavior because your first pattern also includes `=` as one of its matches. You can prevent this behavior by simply excluding `=` from this pattern.

```
au BufNewFile [^=].cpp 0r ~/.vim/templates/skeleton.cpp
au BufNewFile *=.cpp 0r ~/.vim/templates/another.cpp
```